# jQuery part is not working

Tags: jquery

I am using this code for the purpose of TAB key acts as a Enter key to perform opening a link in the HTML page. But this code is valid, when I run it in jsFiddle it works well.
What is the next step that I should do?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>AbT</title>

  <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  //i thought this line is nothing wrong
$('.d').keyup(function(event) 
{
            if(event.which == 9)
                window.open(this.href,"_self");

  });   

 </script>

</head>

<body>


<div>
<a class="d" href="www.google.com">nice</a>
<a class="d" href="www.google.com">ni</a>
<a class="d" href="www.google.com">ni</a>
</div>
<a href="www">mbkb,b</a>
<a href="www.">mbkb,b</a>
<a href="wwcom">mbkb,b</a>
<a href="www.m">mbkb,b</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works in JSFiddle but not on a 'real' document that you've made, it usually means you're missing a `document.ready` JS tag or a `meta charset` HTML tag, or something similar. Add some `http://` prefixes to those Google links too, see if that gets you anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap it inside Document Ready,

```
$(function(){
      $('.d').keyup(function(event) 
      {
                if(event.which == 9)
                    window.open(this.href,"_self");

      });  
 });
```